# How to add Remarketing-Tag to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have this `GA snippet` working good so far. Can you tell me how to set up `Google Adwords Remarketing` within this snippet?

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', '__ga');

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + 'google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    __ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', {
        cookieDomain : 'none'
    });

    __ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking doubleclick support, that [doesn't exist (yet) for Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/).

Answer (score 0):

Adwords remarketing uses a totally different tag, You can login to your adWords account, go to Shared Library, Audiences - look for the Remarketing Tag box on top right and click setup.

However you can use Google Analytics tag for remarketing instead - see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3455600.